# Does integration via partial fractions require simplification beforehand?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I have this practice problem for AP Calc that I've been working on:

integral of (x^5 - 2x^2 + 1) / (x^3 - x) dx

I attempted to solve by integration by parts and am getting a different answer from the answer key.

I apologize in advance as I don't know how to format math equations and symbols on this site. I have my pictures of my work on paper and the answer key below.

[image: Answer Key 1]
[image: Answer Key 2]
[image: My work]

I understand the process on the answer key, but I'm not sure why my process led me to a different answer. The only reason I can think of is that I somehow messed up on the process or that the fraction must be simplified before solving by integration by parts.

The answer I got derives to (2x^2 + x + 1) / (x^3 -x), the fraction portion of the answer key after rewriting with long division.

Comment: A typed version of the pictures would be better for long term use.

Comment: For partial fraction method power of nominator should be less, then power of denominator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Try to substitute your $A,B,C$ back into the decomposition and see if the equality holds. It becomes pretty obvious why it doesn't if you think about where the decomposition rule comes from.

Comment: [Please do not use images to display content which can be typeset.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/)  Personally, I find your notes incredibly hard to read, as they lack contrast, are quite small on my screen, and there are shadows across the work which make it hard to make out some of the notation.  Please take the time to skim over the MathJax tutorial, and format your work appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For partial fractions, degree of the numerator should be less than the degree of denominator. Observe that your solution and the book solution are almost same, there are some extra terms in the book solution that turn out to be the antiderivative of the quotient.